# Separate background image appearing unexpectedly

Tags: css, background

This issue has had me scratching my head for a few days now. I have a website with a set CSS background with no scrolling - works well. However, on pages that are fairly long there appears an exact duplicate of the background, seemingly scrolling in FRONT of the other background.

You can see it illustrated on this page:
http://www.joyrocks.com/corporate/

I've scoured through the CSS and I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I was hoping some fresh eyes could point me in the right direction. Cheers!

**Edit**: Got it solved! Sorry this may have been off-topic. Will keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a second to realize what was happening here. Now I'm not sure why it appears to be duplicated like that. Could have something to do with the background being fixed. I think your main issue here though is the body/html height.

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
```

That only sets the height of the viewport meaning there is still a lot of overflow that's not being covered by that.

I changed height to min-height and it seemed to have fixed the problem :)

```
body,html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed to do! I'll remember to keep an eye out for that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `body,` from this css line:

`body, #section-tophat, #section-footer, #section-sub-footer`

Comment: That only shifts the duplicated background to the top left from top center so they both match.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `body:after` rule that is applying the same style as your body.

There are two offending rules causing this:

```
body, body:after {
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/background-new-2.jpg') top left fixed repeat;
}


body:after, ul.tabs li a.active:after {
    content: "";
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Remove the `body:after` definitions from those and you will be fine.